# Масштабирование серверов

Tags: масштабирование

Есть frontend и backend, backend получает запрос и рассылает некоторые данные всем клиентам а frontend периодически посылает запрос синхронизации (например раз в 10 секунд). Как масштабируют такие системы? Если добавить еще один сервер и соединить с той же базой данных то получается фронтенд одного сервера будет получать данные немедленно лишь от своего сервера а другой ждет синхронизации. Можно это ускорить?

Comment: Если это web посмотрите в сторону отправки данных сразу по появлении, без запросов со стороны клиента, используя server side events или websocket. Например взять модуль nchan для nginx

Comment: И перед любым масштабированием надо посмотреть а где собственно узкое место. Вы уверены например что это именно сервер backend, а не база данных ?

Comment: @Mike, пока не уверен, там vert.x pgClient, пул соединений. Дело в том что данные уже отправляются всем при появлении, т.е. даже до запроса синхронизации. И вот если добавить еще сервер, 2 сервера к одной бд, получится что запрос от клиента к серверу 1 сразу же отправляет событие всем сокетам кто на сервере 1, но не тем кто на сервере 2 поскольку  просто нет сокетов, клиенты сервера 2 должны сами спросить у сервера->бд есть ли что-небудь новое

Comment: @Mike или бд как-небудь может сообщить серверу о новых данных а я не знал?

Comment: Ну это от БД зависит. У postgresql например есть notify. но они только в пределах одного сервера, если кластер делать, то на них опираться нельзя. И вы как то скомканно все описываете, архитектура приложения совершенно не понятна. Зачем например о запросе клиента сообщать всем кто на сервере ? Что кому и о чем надо сообщать. И почему вы используете БД, а не например какую нибудь очередь сообщений. Или почему не используете очередь сообщений совместно с БД

Comment: И почему собственно сервер 1 backend должен передавать 2 backend серверу какие то данные обязательно через БД. может он прямое TCP соединение с ним будет поддерживать и сообщать о чем либо

Comment: @ чат, нужно отправлять сообщение большому количеству клиентов и отправить может кто угодно, онлайн держать тоже важно а бд на случай восстановления если упадет

Comment: @Mike интересно, не подумал о соединении между серверами, но у меня получается много не слишком требовательных запросов которые всем надо отправлять, т.е. нагрузка наверное будет одинаковая тогда

Comment: Ну вот nchan самое то что бы чат поддерживать. он на одном сервере может сообщение 300 тыс клиентов в секунду отправлять. А бакенд сервер с скриптами понадобится только для идентификации и отправки новых сообщений - что бы положить их в БД и отослать nchan. Ну может еще что бы историю отдавать. На одной БД высконагруженные чаты не делают, она у вас первая от запросов ляжет

Comment: ну или опять же БД для сохранения и какая нибудь очередь сообщений в дополнение. т.е. дублировать сообщения и в БД и в очередь. А очередь соответственно рассылает сообщения всем бакенд серверам которые у себя в памяти их сохраняют. (под очередью я имею ввиду какую нибудь MQ, вроде Rabbit или Kafka (она еще и хранить историю может) или еще с десяток разных, надо под специфику и расчетную нагрузку выбирать).

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, буду смотреть, получается в случае падения сервера часть данных можна потерять, да?

Comment: Ну это смотря что использовать и как писать

Comment: Если сначала пишем, потом рассылаем можно ничего и не терять. (предполагается что средство в которое пишите у вас резервировано)